# C coding conventions for function signatures

Tags: c, coding-style

I always follow the existing coding conventions of whatever language I am using and I have started doing C recently. I have noticed that some books display functions with the return value above the rest of the function signature, like this -

```
int
foo(int bar)
{
...
...
...
}
```

I haven't seen this in any other languages I've used. Is this the standard way of presenting C functions these days or is it some old convention that is not in general use anymore?

Comment: It's just a matter of style. Personally I think what you posted is good style. The true rule however is never to impose your own style on others.

Comment: Your team/company decides what is standard. And you should follow that so the code is uniform. Other than that, spacing/indentation, naming conventions, placement of parentheses, brackets and braces can be arbitrary.

Comment: There is no single universally-accepted "best" way to format source code. I find this style quite readable, although I personally don't use it.

Comment: FWIW I think the reason for that style is so that you can search for the definition of the function `foo` (as opposed to other mentions) using `^foo`. If that doesn't sound relevant to your workflow then don't put this rule in your style guide.

Comment: Books do some odd things to save space, and possibly also because they don't have the same aspect ratio as a screen. Personally, I think this style looks extremely ugly. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more to do with getting things like ctags to work effectively.  Or, being able to find the function body itself (rather than any call to it) by simply doing a search for lines starting with funcname.

Ex: `/^funcname`

As long as you use any reasonable indenting style after that, it will be the only place (across an entire code base) where it appears at the very beginning of a line that way.

Comment: Of course today there are programming editors and IDEs which actually parse the code, and can go to definition of a symbol, find all usages of a symbol, etc. So while this may have been a historical reason, it shouldn't be a reason any more...

Comment: Not everybody uses an IDE, especially for C development.  In fact, a large number do not.

Comment: While I don't use it so don't know if it really works, quick googling suggests that for example modern *ctags* & *vim* (and presumably any editor with ctags support) does have "go to definition". Programmer formatting code for tools (instead of using tools to format code for programmer) seems a bit backwards, too.

Comment: vim -t is exceedingly handy from the command line.  Also, this convention arguably makes the code easier to read once you're used to it.  Especially when the return type is verbose (struct some_type *), etc. in combination with a function taking multiple parameters.  Think (as a bad example) of some of the WINAPI functions that take 8 arguments, 7 of which are typically NULL.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are no universal conventions for code formatting in C. The popular styles are named by a project (such as "Linux kernel") or organization (GNU) or book (K&R), or stuff like that.

[Wikipedia has a list of styles.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Styles)

Comment: "That is K&R style" -- Wrong. "It's rarely used today" -- Also wrong if referring to K&R style.

Comment: Your answer changed quite dramatically.

Comment: @AlexReynolds ... which should be pretty fine if it improved.

Comment: @JimBalter You're right. Removed that paragraph. Meant to write this comment immediately, but somehow didn't submit.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this in the Indian Hill Style manual 1990 http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/cstyle.html.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of style and mostly habit. Compiler does not care about that. Use a style in which you are comfortable and something that others easily follow while reading your code.